# PHP Session disallow direct access to a file?

Tags: php

Can with Php session to accept request just from javascript/ajax and disallow request from browser mean disallow direct access to a file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

not based on php session, but you can pass special header with ajax.
like x-requested-with, etc. so that will allow you to identify whether request arrived from ajax or directly ;-)

HTH